# Container that allows fast search and order at the same time

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am getting in scenarios with this problem again and again and I implement different approaches every time. Now I decided to see if the stackoverflow community could suggest something better.

Let say that I have a reconcile API, where the current set of objects in a system need to be reevaluated - and this might take some time. (Note that obtaining the list of IDs of the objects is fast, the evaluation is slow.) It is public API, reconcile could be called irresponsibly. I would like to guarantee that every object in the system is reevaluated after the last call, while at the same time I do not want to reevaluate any object more than once without need. So far so good any set, ordered or unordered will do.

This additional requirement is the key: I would like to rotate the items to prevent in case of reconcile API misuse to reevaluating the same objects that sit on the "top".

... or if I have "A B C D E F" in the system at the first call, I will schedule: "A B C D E F" for reevaluation in this order.

Lets say that A B and C was already evaluated and there are new objects G and H in the system: The new queue should look like: "D E F A B C G H" where "D E F G H A B C" will be better, but it is not critical. I do not want the queue to be "A B C D E F G H" or "D E F A B C D E F G H"

The question is what stl or boost container (or combination) to use to solve this?

Comment: What is reconcile API?

Comment: Good question. Have you considered placing a light wrapper around std::set and std::priority_queue to get what you want?

Comment: "Fast" search? Search how exactly? Is there something which can be used to sort the elements, or do you just mean "linear search without unnecessary slowdowns"? May it is just important to check if some ID exists or not? Or...

Comment: What's wrong with just using a Queue?

Comment: I've used list for something similar when I needed to keep things sorted and grab the first item.  New nodes can be easily inserted in the middle, and newly evaluated nodes can quickly be pushed to the end.

Comment: lets say you keep a memory cache of list of files. Reconcile will be an attempt do discover which files that are in the memory cache no longer in the file system.

Comment: "Fast search? - When I determine which items need to be reevaluated I need to be able to tell which are still in the queue to avoid scheduling them twice - it is just for existence, but yet is still would like to preserve the order, because I do not want to start from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best approach is, if you need anything more complicated than `vector`, `map`, `unordered_map`, `set`, then you should just default to `boost::multi_index_container`. Multi index container has the advantage that it is extremely powerful and flexible and can efficiently support a wide variety of lookup schemes, and it's also quite easily extensible if your needs become greater later on. I would build the entire application that way first, then if you time things and find that you need to optimize, then try to replace relevant multi index containers with optimized data structures tailored to the particular operations you need to support. This saves you an incredible amount of development time fussing over data structure decisions.

Comment: This conveniently glosses over some cost in development time of using slightly error-prone const-reference semantics with modify/replace actions, and hard to understand/predict performance ramifications. I love multi-index for rapid prototyping, but haven't had a project where it survived into production because manually optimized datastructures were significantly faster. What would be desperately needed is something like [`ordered_unique_range_t.`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/container/ordered_unique_range_t.html) as used in Boost Container to avoid overhead

Answer (score 0):

A ring would be the proper data structure for this, but I don't know of any standard implementations.  You can easily simulate it using by using a `std::list` by maintaining iterators to iterate, insert, and detect the end though.

```
std::list<Item>* is = new std::list<Item>();

auto it = is->begin();
auto ir = is->end();

is->insert(ir, i);

if (++it == is->end())
    it = is->begin();
```

This gives `O(1)` insert and `O(1)` iteration.  It adds in additional branch per iteration, but that could be eliminated with a proper ring.

Comment: This code does not compile and `ir++` is undefined behavior.

Comment: How I can avoid scheduling the same object twice?

Comment: That is worse. You should not use standard containers as a pointer allocated by new.

Comment: @gsf I think you mentioned keeping a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @NeilKirk It's only example code, there's no scope so heap or stack is arbitrary.

Comment: You do not need to clear the code. The idea of ring is good, but the problem is that I will have to maintain it as part of every add/remove operation to the system, that creates the same issue - how I can find an object fast in it.

Comment: I don't understand why you would not use the normal way which not only doesn't leak memory, but actually requires less typing.

Comment: For this I will need container that do not invalidate iterators when adding/removing and is fast as set or unordered_set, which I have to check but i do not think is true

Comment: @gsf If you need to remove objects from the system, it's probably easiest to keep a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` to iterators for the values.  You could also make the list intrusive though.

Comment: @gsf The `std::list` iterators aren't invalidated by adding/removing.  So, keeping a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` and a `std:list` is probably easiest.  You could probably wrap them in a class.

Comment: it cannot be list, because search will be O(n) to remove an item. to create a ring I will need to keep iterator while I am adding and removing and the order should be preserved - unordered_set could rehash so I can't use it. std::set might work, but I have to check if the iterators are not invalidated during inserts/removes (but this could be workarounded with keeping the item then converting it back to iterator after the operation)

Comment: @gsf You can iterate over the `std::list` which is `O(1)`, but for `O(1)` lookup/remove also use a `std::unordered_map` to the iterator for the element (e.g. `std::unordered_map<Item, std::list<Item>::iterator>`).  If you can add members to the `Item` class (`prev`, `next`), you could probably eliminate the need for the `std::unordered_map` entirely.